# Deserializing real world JSON data

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am unfortunately forced to deal with a raft of JSON data and so inevitably defaulted to json.net, wherein I discovered the 'documentation' deals exclusively in fancifully simplistic examples.

My data contains the following 'instance', as an example.

```
"team" : [{
        "id" : "8",
        "vendor-id" : "8",
        "statsinc-id" : "8",
        "team-name" : "",
        "team-nickname" : "Pistons",
        "rank" : ""
    }, {
        "id" : "51",
        "vendor-id" : "29",
        "statsinc-id" : "29",
        "team-name" : "",
        "team-nickname" : "Grizzlies",
        "rank" : ""
    }
]
```

Now bear in mind either side of this string/whatever the json term is, is a large amount of other data.

There are three problems.

1. I followed the documentation and couldn't actually get it to spit out any kind of value (I was trying to get the id field).
2. The 'attributes' have hyphens in them, c# doesn't allow hyphens in variable/property names so how do you deal with that?
3. In the above instance there are two of each 'attribute' so presumably the latter would overwrite the former in the object, would I need a list of objects and then somehow figure out a way to insert each value sequentially?

I find the whole thing needlessly complicated and am therefore in dire need of help - it's a lot to ask but if someone could show me how to get both the 'team-nickname' values out I'd be massively grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the reason you find the "whole thing needlessly complicated" is because your question shows quite a misunderstanding of JSON, the square bracket after "team": denotes the start of an array, so the duplicates are not duplicates, they are different entries. I suggest you study something a little better before criticising it, might i suggest the w3c site: http://www.w3schools.com/json/ ??

Comment: Create base objects for each type, then use composition on to a bigger object that you can use to deserialize. Also you could try using Dictionary<string,list<dictionary<string,string>>> the first dictionary maps the base object the list contains multiple dictionaries that maps to the inner objects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the name issue, you should use the [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) to specify what the property names are (when they can't be inferred, or you want it different).

There are multiple items, but they're in an array so that you can access both. They do not overwrite each other.

You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate JSON and [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to try to generate C# classes based on JSON.

Your JSON, as-is, is not valid full JSON. I wrapped it in `{}` to make it an object, and then was able to create these classes:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Team> team { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("vendor-id")]
    public string VendorId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("statsinc-id")]
    public string StatsIncId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("team-name")]
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("team-nickname")]
    public string TeamNickname { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("rank")]
    public string Rank { get; set; }
}

// this works!
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
var nicknames = obj.team.Select(x => x.TeamNickname); // "Pistons", "Grizzlies"
```

I used `JsonProperty` to specify all of the property names in `Team` (not just the hyphenated ones), so that I can use the C#/.Net standard property capitalization while still serializing and deserializing correctly.

Comment: Tricksy, does the job brilliantly and should hopefully help me sort out the rest of the data, many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Create a class for your team object:

```
public class Team {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int ID {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "vendor-id")]
    public int VendorID {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "statsinc-id")]
    public int StatsIncID {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "team-name")]
    public string TeamName {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "team-nickname")]
    public string TeamNickname {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "rank")]
    public Rank {get;set;}
}
```

Then, you can deserialize your JSON by doing:

```
var listOfTeams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Team>(inputString);
```

Answer (score 3):

With regards to 2. when you create your class that you are going to be deserializing to you would mark your properties as such :

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "team-name")]
public string teamName { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "team-nickname")]
public string teamNickname { get; set; }
```

As the other answer said this is an array of teams so they would deserialize to different instances of your "Team" object.